# SharePoint 2010 and SAML 2.0

Tags: sharepoint-2010, saml-2.0

Can I send SAML 2.0 token to SharePoint 2010 for authentication? I found a sample code in MSDN that connect office 365 in the cloud for the authentication, but the sample code uses SAML 1.1 token.
Does SharePoint work with SAML 2.0 token as well?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. Sharepoint supports natively SAML 1.1 for claim-based authentication. To handle SAML 2.0 tokens in Sharepoint 2010, you currently have 3 choices:

1. develop a custom authentication provider using WIF. That shouldn't
   be that complex to do as SAML 2.0 was recently integrated in WIF.
   You'll find the library and code samples here:
   http://connect.microsoft.com/site1168/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=36088
2. use Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS). The general idea of
   this solution is that Sharepoint delegates authentication to ADFS,
   which is configured as a SAML 2.0 Service Provider. Main advantage
   of this solution: configuration/installation only, no development.
   Obvious downside: much more complex architecture.
3. wait for Microsoft to implement SAML 2.0 in a future Sharepoint
   Service Pack :)

Comment: Can you please share the experience you have on this. I am trying the 2nd approach. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom [Saml2SecurityTokenHandler Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.saml2.saml2securitytokenhandler.aspx)

Comment: so that means out of the box, SharePoint 2010 is using WIF but does not support SAML 2.0.